# more efficient T-SQL statement

Tags: t-sql

Good Day,

At the moment we use a SQL as our Database for our Solarwinds Product i have written a query thats just below, i just want to know if there is a more efficient way of executing the query.

whats happening here is we get different values for a device that is being monitored and if a condition has changed then alert it just seem that the WHERE clause is overkill.

so what i want is if AssignmentName = x and if currentvalue is not = to the 'y'value then alert.

```
FROM 
CustomPollerStatus INNER JOIN CustomPollerAssignmentView ON              CustomPollerStatus.CustomPollerAssignmentID =   CustomPollerAssignmentView.CustomPollerAssignmentID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomPollers ON CustomPollerAssignmentView.CustomPollerID =     CustomPollers.CustomPollerID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodes ON CustomPollerAssignmentView.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID) 

where AssignmentName = 'a' and currentvalue != '24'
and AssignmentName = 'b' and currentvalue != '1'
and AssignmentName = 'c' and currentvalue != 'RUN'
and AssignmentName = 'd' and currentvalue != 'RUN'
and AssignmentName = 'e' and currentvalue != '72'
and AssignmentName = 'f' and currentvalue != '30'
and AssignmentName = 'g' and currentvalue != '72'
and AssignmentName = 'h' and currentvalue != '30'
and AssignmentName = 'i' and currentvalue != '276'
and AssignmentName = 'j' and currentvalue != '72'
```

i am new to TSQL any knowledge would be great on creating a more efficient query

Comment: I would'nt think this query would return any resluts?"

Comment: Did you test this before posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you meant to write

```
SELECT * 

FROM CustomPollerStatus 
    INNER JOIN CustomPollerAssignmentView ON CustomPollerStatus.CustomPollerAssignmentID = CustomPollerAssignmentView.CustomPollerAssignmentID  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomPollers ON CustomPollerAssignmentView.CustomPollerID = CustomPollers.CustomPollerID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodes ON CustomPollerAssignmentView.NodeID = Nodes.NodeID) 

where (AssignmentName = 'a' and currentvalue != '24')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'b' and currentvalue != '1')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'c' and currentvalue != 'RUN')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'd' and currentvalue != 'RUN')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'e' and currentvalue != '72')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'f' and currentvalue != '30')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'g' and currentvalue != '72')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'h' and currentvalue != '30')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'i' and currentvalue != '276')
    OR (AssignmentName = 'j' and currentvalue != '72')
```

or maybe you meant

```
...
WHERE (AssignmentName IN  ('a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g', 'h','i','j')
    AND CurrentValue NOT IN ('24', '1','RUN','72','30''276')
```

Either way the query wouldn't be more efficient. If you are having performance problems, I would look at your indexes.

Comment: The else is not the same 'a' '1' would break

Comment: Thank you, that's wicked, these are some of the first SQL queries i have wrote, just want to make sure i am on the right track, apologizes i should have included the Select Statement. wanted to see what alternative i could use to arrive at the same answer :)